# How can I use .patch file with .jar?

Tags: jar, patch

I have a protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar file and a protobuf.patch file.
How can I patch protobuf.patch file to protobuf.jar file?

Protobuf.patch file:

```
diff --git b/OsmAnd-java/src/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java 
a/OsmAnd-java/src/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java
index ad43f96..45004e2 100644
--- b/OsmAnd-java/src/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java
+++ a/OsmAnd-java/src/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java
@@ -32,6 +32,7 @@ package com.google.protobuf;

 import java.io.IOException;
...
```

Comment: `man patch`. Can't say more unless I see the start of `protobuf.patch`.

Comment: My system is windows 8.1, not linux.

Comment: That complicates matters (and should be in tags). I believe you should be able to use [this Windows implementation](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm), or do it in Cygwin. Basically run `patch -p1 < protobuf.patch` should work. EDIT: it seems to be a git diff; so `git apply protobuf.patch` (presumably you have git, if not install git-bash).

Comment: Seems like the question should be more along the lines of what patch tools are available in Windows?

Comment: Yes, I want patch tools are available in windows.

Comment: Hi Amadan, How can I use it?
I have been installed cygwin, where will I copy protobuf.patch? When I run "patch -p1 < protobuf.patch", it said couldn't search protobuf.patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply .patch file to .jar. .jar is zip archive for compiled Java binary and .patch file modifies Java sources.